# Facebook SDK on Android 2.3 - Page not found

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem with Facebook login on Android 2.3.3 (HTC Wildifre S). When I click on Login to Facebook button, it redirects me to Facebook app - I put there my login and password. Then I get redirected to web browser and I must login again on web page and then web browser redirects me to URL like **fbconnect://success?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx?expires_at=yyyyy**.
Web browser cannot handle this URL so I get page not found error and I'm not redirected to my app again.

I have Facebook App, I added package and class name in config, I have properly configured appId in my Android app and I generated key hash and put in my Facebook App config.

**Strange thing is that it is working on Android 4.1 (Samsung Galaxy S Plus).**

Here is code of my activity :

```
package com.example.apptest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;


public class FBLogin extends Activity {
    public static final int GAME_THREAD_DELAY = 4000;
    //private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

    Facebook fb;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    private Button button_fblogin;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin);

        Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        button_fblogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fblogin_btn);
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session == null){
            Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "session == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null){
                Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "session= new Session()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)){
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }
        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "updateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            button_fblogin.setText(R.string.button_fblogout);
            button_fblogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });
        } else {
            button_fblogin.setText(R.string.fblogin_button_title);
            button_fblogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }



    private void onClickLogin(){
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()){
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "onClickLogin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogout(){
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()){
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fblogin, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted solution if it helped you or comment if and why it didn't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Facebook App on the phone.

For some reason that solved the problem for me. I assume it tries to use some native Facebook App procedures. They are either not correctly linked or outdated.

My guess is, that removing the Facebook App entirely or reinstalling it would solve it as well.